# mysql dynamic var

Tags: sql, mysql

A little confused how to create a query and set a dynamic var in the query for output.

Lets say I have a basic table with the following

```
id | name | type | location
```

Now I want to do a query and select all data pretty simple stuff

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

Which will give me ie.

```
1 | batman | scifi | row a
2 | matrix | scifi | row b
```

Bit I want to add a dynamic row to tell me its a video. ie

```
id| name   | type  | location | category
1 | batman | scifi | row a    | video
2 | matrix | scifi | row b    | video
```

How can I add this to a query ??

Hope someone can advise!!

Thank you in advance

Comment: How does that differ from just adding a `category` column?

Comment: I knew that Q would come up. Im building a query to go into apache solr so I need to set category during query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  *, 
        'video' AS category
FROM    TABLE
```

Comment: Now i feel really dumb !!  Works a charm

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT *, 'video' category FROM table`

That will add a category column that has a value of `video` for all rows. Is this what you meant?

Comment: @tatu: you're missing the AS keyword.

Comment: Some databases do not require the AS keyword.  Not sure about mysql (which the OP tagged)

Comment: At least MySQL 5 does not need it.